# Are Scala STM and AKKA Agent two competing paradigm?

Tags: scala

I just start checking our AKKA Agent, as well as STM and notice that they seem to have the same function?

I'm wondering if there is in Scala concurrent guru here would shed the light on there difference from return on experience. When to use one instead of the other.

Comment: Well... I am not an expert on this... but AFAIK `Agents` are `STM meets Actors`... So... no... `STM` and `Agents` are not two competing paradigms... `Agents` are just `STM` enablers in `Actor` paradigm.

Comment: thanks, i kind of see it now

Comment: Please note that the migration guide for AKKA 2.3.x states that both concepts are deprecated

Comment: Alright i stay away from it and think differently then.